# run series of test functions to appear as separate tests within browserstack

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, selenium, nightwatch.js, browserstack

I have a series of functions like below, that thread through a web application that simulate login, and then runs through many features of the web app. I am using JS, nightwatch.js, and selenium via browserstack.. the problem is, it all reports through browser stack as one large test with this approach; how could I get each function to report within browserstack as separate test?

```
this.Settings = function(browser) {
         browser

         .url(Data.urls.settings)
         .waitForElementVisible("div.status-editor .box", 1000)

         Errors.checkForErrors(browser);

         browser.end();
};  

this.TeamPanel = function(browser) {
        browser

        Errors.checkForErrors(browser);

        browser.end();
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using the same remote browser instance for all the test functions which therefore are being run as a single test case on BrowserStack. You need to create a new driver instance before every test function. You can either implement that parallelisation logic in your framework or use any sample nightwatch framework like the one here: https://github.com/browserstack/nightwatch-browserstack

Comment: So adding: bs_local.stop(function(){}); before the close of each function?